# Spring Boot 2.0.0 War deployment issue with Jboss 6.4

Tags: spring-boot, jboss

We have a live project in Spring Boot 1.3.3 with JBoss server 6.4. Now we are planning to move to spring boot 2.0.0 but while deploying war on the server it gives errors. As per the link [Spring boot 2.0.1 with Jboss eap 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002767/spring-boot-2-0-1-with-jboss-eap-6-4)
It says either we have to move to JBoss 7 or we have to downgrade the spring boot version.
Is there any other workaround like changing servlet jar from JBoss server or excluding it from the pom.xml file. Coz it is impossible to upgrade JBoss version as it is deployed at the client side and it is live.

Comment: Those are your only options. Don't start messing around with jars in JBoss (or those shipped with your servlet container in general) as that will lead to other issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot 2.0.1 with Jboss eap 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50002767/spring-boot-2-0-1-with-jboss-eap-6-4)